# Manifest merge failed

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Estoy intentano ejecutar un proyecto android en react native y me encuentro con el siguiente error:

> :app:processDebugManifest
>   /Users/me/project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value
>   value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 is also present at
>   [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   value=(26.1.0). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>   element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information
>   about the manifest merger.
>
> :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0). Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Este es mi Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/> 
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Este es mi build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 27
        versionName "5.1.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (project(':pushwoosh-react-native-plugin'))
    {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Me han sugerido añadir al manifest tools:replace="android:value" pero esto no resuelve mi problema.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar en el `build.gradle` esta línea `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"` por esta `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"` y el `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` por `buildToolsVersion "26.1.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa el mensaje de error:

> Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value
>   value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Sugiere definir el meta dato conteniendo el valor de la versión, por lo tanto agrega dentro de `<application>` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   ...
   ...
   <meta-data
       tools:replace="android:value"
       android:name="android.support.VERSION"
       android:value="26.0.2" />

</application>
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Jorgesys

Comment: Hola @JhonmerAraujo comenta si te fue de ayuda al implementar esta solución

Comment: No, me devuelve lo siguiente: El prefijo "tools" para el atributo "tools:replace" asociado a un tipo de elemento "meta-data" no está enlazado.

Comment: @JhonmerAraujo lo agregaste en tu AndroidManifest.xml dentro de <application> ?

Comment: <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data
       tools:replace="android:value"
       android:name="android.support.VERSION"
       android:value="26.0.2" />
      <activity
        ...
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75511/discussion-between-jhonmer-araujo-and-jorgesys).

Comment: Listo. Me faltaba colocar en la cabecera del manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: @JhonmerAraujo no puedes agregar propiedades si no tienes definidos los namespaces, si te marca que no existe la propiedad , usando Alt+Enter  puedes agregar los namespaces.

Answer (score -1):

no te preocupes te ayudo a modificarlo y listo ;3

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 27
        versionName "7.1.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x58"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x82":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 162156 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (project(':pushwoosh-react-native-plugin'))
    {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.jhs'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.2.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:51.9.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "lytr", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.8.7"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

de nada :3

Comment: Gracias por tu interés en participar en la comunidad Yaz!, te sugiero revisar [answer]. Saludos!